# Format datestring dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sqlite

The user input the date as DD/MM/YYYY and sqlite needs to convert it to YYYY-MM-DD.

How can i do that?

Tested that i done:

```
    strftime("%Y-%m-%d", "03/01/2000")
```

Comment: The fact that sqlite is an embedded DBMS means that it is expected that much functionality will be implemented in the host language.  Before sending a date string to the database, use the available date-time library functions in the host language to read, validate and convert the date to a string format compatible with sqlite.  This is likely more reliable than parsing the string with the limited SQL expressions.  There is no exception handling nor advanced user-input validation in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) does not help in this case.
You have to use [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) and concatenation:

```
substr('03/01/2000', 7) || '-' || substr('03/01/2000', 4, 2) || '-' || substr('03/01/2000', 1, 2)
```

Result:

```
2000-01-03
```

Note: If you plan to store dates with SQLite, store them in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. 
It is comparable and for it you can use `strftime()` to format it anyway you want.